# Как связать два radiobutton с двумя select?

Tags: javascript, html, select, radio

Здравствуйте, есть к примеру 2 select'а и 2 набора radio кнопок, вот так выглядит:

```html
<select id="select1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <select>
    <br>
    <input name="select1" type="radio">1
    <input name="select1" type="radio">2
    <input name="select1" type="radio">3
    <input name="select1" type="radio">4
    <input name="select1" type="radio">5
    
    <select id="select2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <select>
    <br>
    <input name="select2" type="radio">1
    <input name="select2" type="radio">2
    <input name="select2" type="radio">3
    <input name="select2" type="radio">4
    <input name="select2" type="radio">5
```

Как сделать так, чтоб radio кнопками с name="select1" можно было переключать select с id="select1", а radio кнопками с name="select2" можно было переключать select с id="select2"?

Comment: Немного оффтоп: зачем дублировать? Просто практика?

Comment: @user202854 Не совсем дублирование, с 2 радио и 2 селектами возникла сложность, т.к. 2 пачкой радио можно было управлять 1 селектом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input:radio[name=select1]').on('change', function () {
    var select = $('input:radio[name=select1]:checked').val();
    $('#select1 option[value="'+select+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});

$('input:radio[name=select2]').on('change', function () {
    var select = $('input:radio[name=select2]:checked').val();
    $('#select2 option[value="'+select+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <select>
    <br>
    <input name="select1" value="1" type="radio">1
    <input name="select1" value="2" type="radio">2
    <input name="select1" value="3" type="radio">3
    <input name="select1" value="4" type="radio">4
    <input name="select1" value="5" type="radio">5
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="select2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <select>
    <br>
    <input name="select2" value="1" type="radio">1
    <input name="select2" value="2" type="radio">2
    <input name="select2" value="3" type="radio">3
    <input name="select2" value="4" type="radio">4
    <input name="select2" value="5" type="radio">5
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы в опции селектов добавил атрибут `value` и сделал бы так :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById(this.name).value = this.value;
  });
});

// и обратное действие
[...document.getElementsByTagName('select')].forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.querySelector(`input[name="${this.id}"][value="${this.value}"]`).checked = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<input name="select1" value="1" type="radio">1
<input name="select1" value="2" type="radio">2
<input name="select1" value="3" type="radio">3
<input name="select1" value="4" type="radio">4
<input name="select1" value="5" type="radio">5
<select id="select1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
<select>
<br>
<input name="select2" value="1" type="radio">1
<input name="select2" value="2" type="radio">2
<input name="select2" value="3" type="radio">3
<input name="select2" value="4" type="radio">4
<input name="select2" value="5" type="radio">5    
<select id="select2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Уверен, второй вариант сам сделаешь...

```js
const input1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="select1"]');

const select_1 = document.querySelector('#select1');

for (let i = 0; i < input1.length; i++) {
  input1[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    select_1.selectedIndex = i;
  })
}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <select>
    <br>
    <input name="select1" type="radio">1
    <input name="select1" type="radio">2
    <input name="select1" type="radio">3
    <input name="select1" type="radio">4
    <input name="select1" type="radio">5
```