# Как при выборе select отметить нужный checkbox по значению data выбранного значения select?

Tags: javascript, select, checkbox, javascript-events

```html
<select class="select" id="select">
  <option value="all" data-size="all" class="subSelect">Все размеры</option>
  <option value="big" data-size="big" class="subSelect">Большие</option>
  <option value="middle" data-size="middle" selected class="subSelect">Средние</option>
  <option value="small" data-size="small" class="subSelect">Маленькие</option>
</select>

<div class='boxes'>
  <label class="box">
    Маленький
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="small" class="checkbox" value="small">
  </label> <br>
  <label class="box">
    Средний
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="middle" class="checkbox" value="middle">
  </label><br>
  <label class="box">
    Большой
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="big" class="checkbox" value="big">
  </label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как связать два radiobutton с двумя select?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782859/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-radiobutton-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** *Используя jquery:*

```js
$("#select").on("change", function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
  $("input[type='checkbox'][data-size='"+$(this).find("option:selected").data('size')+"']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" id="select">
  <option value="all" data-size="all" class="subSelect">Все размеры</option>
  <option value="big" data-size="big" class="subSelect">Большие</option>
  <option value="middle" data-size="middle" selected class="subSelect">Средние</option>
  <option value="small" data-size="small" class="subSelect">Маленькие</option>
</select>

<div class='boxes'>
  <label class="box">
    Маленький
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="small" class="checkbox" value="small">
  </label> <br>
  <label class="box">
    Средний
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="middle" class="checkbox" value="middle">
  </label><br>
  <label class="box">
    Большой
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="big" class="checkbox" value="big">
  </label><br>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2.** *На чистом javascript:*

```js
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function()
{
  let chekbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  for(let i = 0; i < chekbox.length; i++)
  {
    chekbox[i].checked = (chekbox[i].dataset.size == this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.size) ? true : false;
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="select" id="select">
  <option value="all" data-size="all" class="subSelect">Все размеры</option>
  <option value="big" data-size="big" class="subSelect">Большие</option>
  <option value="middle" data-size="middle" selected class="subSelect">Средние</option>
  <option value="small" data-size="small" class="subSelect">Маленькие</option>
</select>

<div class='boxes'>
  <label class="box">
    Маленький
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="small" class="checkbox" value="small">
  </label> <br>
  <label class="box">
    Средний
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="middle" class="checkbox" value="middle">
  </label><br>
  <label class="box">
    Большой
    <input type="checkbox" data-size="big" class="checkbox" value="big">
  </label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: да именно то, но только нужен на чистом js

Comment: @Mario добавили вариант на чистом javascript

Comment: Да все круто, только почему то теперь, при выборе несколько одинаковых checkbox-ов не работает, а на jquery работает

Comment: @Mario упростили второй вариант. *при выборе несколько одинаковых checkbox-ов не работает* - непонятно, покажите пример кода

Comment: Все класс)) спасибо

Comment: @Mario обратите внимание, сейчас код еще раз обновлен - ранее была проверка по value, сейчас проверка идет по *data-set* выбранной *option* как и требуется в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то